# Test function declared in other file with jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a problem to test a function. The function is defined in app.js, the testfile is app.test.js
How can I import the function, so that I can test it?
my Goal is to unit test only the function without all other stuff which is in the app.js

app.js

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const data = require('../shoppinglist/data.json')
const baseUrl = '/api/v1/shoppingLists'
module.exports = {app, client, listener, getNewestId}

function getNewestId(obj){
    let idArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        idArray.push(obj[i].id)
    }
    return Math.max(...idArray)
}
```

app.test.js

```
const appPath = '../src/app'
describe('getNewestId from Valid array', () => {
    it('should return id 3', async () => {
        jest.mock(shoppingListDataPath, () => [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "filled shopping list",
                "location": "lidl",
                "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                "priority": 1,
                "isFinished": false,
                "items": [{"count":1, "name": "vodka" }, {"count":1, "name": "vodka" }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "filled shopping list2",
                "location": "lidl2",
                "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                "priority": 1,
                "isFinished": false,
                "items": [{"count":1, "name": "vodka" }, {"count":1, "name": "vodka" }
                ]
            }
        ])
        const {app} = require(appPath)
        app.getNewestId = jest.fn()
        expect(app.getNewestId()).toEqual(200)
    })
})
```

I guess it's something wrong with the requires / imports. But I can only use here require.

Comment: Can you try to remove the curly braces around `app` in the require call, and console.log? What does it give you?

Comment: `getNewestId` is not a property of `app`. Also, i's unclear what's your intention with this code. If you want to test the function, you shouldn't mock it.

Comment: Id like to just test the function only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require the `getNewestId` function and test it like this:

```js
const { getNewestId } = require("./app");

const testData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "filled shopping list",
    "location": "lidl",
    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
    "priority": 1,
    "isFinished": false,
    "items": [{"count":1, "name": "vodka" }, {"count":1, "name": "vodka" }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "filled shopping list2",
    "location": "lidl2",
    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
    "priority": 1,
    "isFinished": false,
    "items": [{"count":1, "name": "vodka" }, {"count":1, "name": "vodka" }]
  }
];

describe("getNewestId from Valid array", () => {
  it("should return id 3", () => {
    expect(getNewestId(testData)).toEqual(3);
  })
});
```

If you want to use unit tests, make sure the functions you test are [pure](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976). After you familiarize yourself with this, consider testing your application on other levels, for example, writing tests that will hit your API ;)